# Does a library solution exist for? Assert array and single for a function that returns union type array or single

Tags: typescript

Does a library solution exist?  Does exist a library that has more such hacks like this or like findOrReject for typescript projects?
There are many functions in libraries that can process both single and multiple objects.
But the problems appear of type narrowing. I also add a type definition function that negotiates the type.
I am interested in if a ready solution is present. If it does not. Advise me on optimizing my approach
if I move it to my project library. There are examples of asserts and their usage.
There is a typescript [playground version](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAJwKZRMsBlGYDmANqgPLICCyyAhgJ4AUAlAFyIDOUye+iAPu524BtALqIA3gChEiCAg6IAbtS7UwURAF5EAWWpQAFgDoaYACZwAtkwDc0xAHoAVE-uIniADJx8MCLLVEACNURDMYYGBUNHUjNw8AWkQASWBEBEJadLBQ1GJLVHVEGDZEAAc0NkKNPERDUMISqAAaFHRMJAyshFRWvKq2jCw6gwamuJl3RCTUxEC8MpANMpVqAqho4tLAlRpaVvrOpcWa7cI2ODmqOgmZJwd7CMR6ZVUigB5EAAYjAFZGCRuQYdRAAcjY3GIoPsAF9JPY0EMkEJQT1Qa1QVAAO5wdFgwxoVCgkSSOGSUCQWAIbKZXAEYhMVgcLgEQEyORgBRmfTULTArB0oikCjXBiMOwyahsKrIKCChncqDURj2BHtYaK6h2MkU6DwTpgTKePCoNiMgQs-CiNmyeQaTV8xEdeXCyh7Wz2KUyqBuuj0TUqmRqpFhHna+EchSNHJ8rouj2RuDEIyEHz0aOocWOBzTBIAPgt3BptEkkY0GdK2i6xpyZqzDhzCXzhYI1q6pfkSdQKbTFfF8N1VKQXuiPtF7wAKnn6HBWBO+IgJ6IWHNpaPSpcSovrVIZE96ABCX20IwlY8zxgA3eTAlwLGIHL3gCiVDgyHooKfAA8yqhoKgzCuPYjEQF10iCAArP9TgfOANGoQhUyxACjFBfsZDhHVwD1akR1lF1J2nWdFwXJcRBXPCoA3LYSOvfdj1PNhzzgS8bRkW970fRAX2QN8P2-X9-0AiF6VCOBIOgkDjxosA4LmRC7xQtCJUQTCgA)

```js
function returnSingleOrArray(): string | string[] {
  const variant = Math.random();
  /**
   * Logic can be different.
   * - If only one element is present in the list, return only one, else return the list.
   * - If an input parameter is an array, then output is also array.
   */
  if (variant < 0.5) {
    return 'single'
  }

  return ['one', 'two', 'three']
}

function onlySingle(): string {
  const data = returnSingleOrArray();
  assertSingle(data)
  
  return data;
}

function onlyLines(): string[] {
  const data = returnSingleOrArray();
  assertArray(data)
  
  return data;
}

const line = onlySingle();
console.log(line); // --> string only
const lines = onlyLines(); // --> string[] only
console.log(lines);

function assertArray<T>(o: T | T[]): asserts o is T[] {
  if (!Array.isArray(o)) {
    throw new Error('Expected array. Single object is not allowed.');
  }
}

function assertSingle<T>(o: T | T[]): asserts o is T {
  if (Array.isArray(o)) {
    throw new Error('Expected single object. Array is not allowed.');
  }
}
```

This can sound childish. I ask because I see many such tiny lifehacks in the network, so I think I miss a core functionality or an external library for such hacks. I will remove this question if it is so stupid.
Regards.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't quite understand what question you're asking.  Your code works, and there's no major issue in it that I see, but anything else I say about it feels like just opinion, which is out of scope for Stack Overflow.  Could you [edit] your post to make it very obvious what the question is, and what objective criteria one could use to judge an answer?

Comment: Please post code without error as examples, see https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20170324-00/?p=95815

Comment: I don't think your question is "stupid", but I'm concerned that it might not be [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for Stack Overflow because you seem to be asking for recommendations for libraries (see point #3 in that link).  As I said before, your code works and I don't see anything major wrong with it, so I can't imagine an answer here that isn't just opinion.  If opinion were on-topic, I'd write an answer that says "this looks fine, just keep using this", but it's not, so I won't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually return type depends on parameter type, so you should just declare overloads with appropriate types.
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads

```
function dependsOnArg(arg: string[]): string[]; // 1
function dependsOnArg(arg: string): string;     // 2
function dependsOnArg(arg: string | string[]): string | string[] {
  if (Array.isArray(arg)) 
      return ['1'];
  else
    return '2';
}

const arr = dependsOnArg(['a', 'b']); // 1
arr.push('qwe');

const str = dependsOnArg('a');        // 2
str.charCodeAt(0);
```

If return type doesn't depends on arguments nothing can help you (use [type guards or asserts](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) or helpers like those in your example)

Alternatively: just rewrite function to always return array. You will save function's user a lot of if-elses.

Comment: I agree. I am asking about. Because in network I so few same cases. And I start to meet them again and again. I am interested if a core or library solution exists. This asserts a trivial.

Comment: @VictorShelepen  I added sample. // [so few](https://translate.google.com/?sl=en&tl=ru&text=%20so%20few&op=translate) <--> seen a few. big difference

Comment: Your, example is very good. I've played in TS playground. I start to understand how function overloads can help. I knew about it. But I could not imagine such usage.